# Share session between sockets. (Log out user from all active tabs)

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I am building simple studying chat application using node.js express framework. And I have one problem.
If user have multiple tabs active, and he logs out on one tab. I want to close connection to other tabs and make redirect to login page. But I've met a problem. Even if user has logged out other sockets session is not changed(I am using passport.socketio package, so I have current user at socket.handshake.user). What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have n different tabs that is actually n number of different sockets. One way of achieving what you want is make all the sockets from a specific user join a single [room](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms).

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join(socket.handshake.user.id);
    // rest of your code
}
```

And in the logout code emit an event "logout" to that specific room.

```
io.sockets.in(socket.handshake.user.id).emit('logout')
```

Now in the client side you can write a event listener on "logout" that redirects to your desired location.

Comment: Thanks. So I need access to my sockets at controller?

Comment: yes, you will need the io object in your controllers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your app you will have to look through all open sockets, find the matching user name and terminate them by hand.

Comment: But how I can handle logout? I am doing it through http.